# Initiating an action based on product type

Tags: object-oriented, ruby

I am starting my studies with Ruby and OO and I have received a test to do about OO. I am looking for new ways to improve the scenario following object-oriented concepts. Is there a better way to develop this design applying polymorphism?

Here is my problem:

1. If the product is physical, I have to generate a shipping label.
2. If it's a book, I have to mention that this product doesn't have taxes.
3. If the product is a membership, I have to activate the signature and notify the buyer via email.
4. If the product is digital, I have to send an email for the buyer and give a $10 discount for this product.

```
class Product
  attr_reader :name, :description, :type, :amount
  include Shipping
  include Discount

    def initialize(name, description, type, amount)
        @name = name
        @description = description
        @type = type
        @amount = amount
    end 
end

class Physical < Product
    def initialize(name, description, type, amount)
        super(name, description, type, amount)
    end

    def shipping
        case @type
            when :book
                create_shipping_label
                notify_buyer_product_without_taxes
            else
                create_shipping_label
            end
    end

    def discount
        discount_for_physical_product = 0.0
      return discount_for_physical_product
    end
end

class Membership < Product
    attr_reader :membership_status

    def initialize(name, description, type, amount)
        super(name, description, type, amount)
    end

  def activate_membership()
    @membership_status = true;
  end

  def shipping
    notify_buyer_via_email
    activate_membership
  end

  def discount
    discount_for_membership_product = 0
    return discount_for_membership_product
  end
end

class Digital < Product

    def initialize(name, description, type, amount)
        super(name, description, type, amount)
    end

  def shipping
    notify_buyer_via_email
  end   

  def discount
    discount_for_digital_product = 10.00
    return discount_for_digital_product
  end
end

module Discount

    def prepare_discount(order)
        total_discount = 0
        order.get_items.each do |item|
             total_discount += item.product.discount
        end
        return total_discount
    end

    def discount
        discount_default = 0.0
        return discount_default
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a conditional based on the type of object. You can apply the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactoring pattern.

In this case, you might have a base class `Product`, with subclasses `DigitalProduct` and `PhysicalProduct` which each implement `discount()`. I don't think it's sensible to have a `MembershipProduct` class - membership should be related to the buyer. From an OO perspective, it should feel wrong when you have methods like `discount_for_X()` - the method should be part of the respective class so that you can make use of polymorphism.

Comment: thank you ! One question, if business rules for shipping and discount are in product class is not wrong ? I mean would it be better if I use the polymorphism in this case and call methods from shipping and discount module to deal with it ? This way I would use polymorphism and follow the first's SOLID rule )Single responsibility principle). Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking. To follow site rules, you should post a completed sample in order to get appropriate feedback. See [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Ruby expert

## Type parameter

The main thing that bothers me with you code is the `type` parameter given when constructing a `Product`'s instance. This goes against OO principles and leads to bad code for the following reason: you have to manage conditional explicitely in code with control structures (if, switch) instead of delegating this responsibility to the compiler/interpreter by using polymorphism.

Removing this would need to introduce a both `Book` class and a `GenericProduct` class which is basically representing all physical products but books.

## Common discount method

Another thing is that the `discount` method is common to all products and differs only in the data (and not in the behavior). This can be implemented in `Product` and request the discount value in the constructor.

## Create local variable and directly return it

This is useless and only introduce visual noise. You can directly return the value.

## Similitude between `Membership` and `Digital Product`

It looks like `Membership` is also a special kind of digital product and that a relationship between them can exist (they both require to send an email when shipping). However I'm not entirely sure about that so feel free to ignore the end of the resulting code listing.

## Reviewed code

```
class Product
  attr_reader :name, :description, :amount, :discount
  include Shipping
  include Discount

    def initialize(name, description, amount, discount)
        @name = name
        @description = description
        @amount = amount
        @discount = discount
    end 

    def discount
        return @discount
    end
end

class PhysicalProduct < Product
    def initialize(name, description, amount)
        super(name, description, amount, 0.0)
    end

    def shipping
        create_shipping_label
        notify_buyer_product_without_taxes if free_of_taxes
    end
end

class GenericProduct < PhysicalProduct
    def initialize(name, description, amount)
        super(name, description, amount)
    end

    def free_of_taxes
        return false
    end
end

class Book < PhysicalProduct
    def initialize(name, description, amount)
        super(name, description, amount)
    end

    def free_of_taxes
        return true
    end
end

class DigitalProduct < Product

    def initialize(name, description, amount, discount = 10.00)
        super(name, description, amount, discount)
    end

    def shipping
        notify_buyer_via_email
    end
end

class Membership < DigitalProduct
    attr_reader :membership_status

    def initialize(name, description, amount)
        super(name, description, amount, 0.0)
    end

    def activate_membership()
        @membership_status = true;
    end

    def shipping
        super
        activate_membership
    end
end
```